# handler, runnable and services: I put everything together and it doesn't really work

Tags: java, android, service, handler, runnable

I wanted to create a service, that runs a method after 10 seconds over and over again, until I stop it. It doesn't work. Can somebody help me?

```
package com.example.tauben;


import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Reminder extends Service {


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run(){
            f();
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 10000);
}
public void f(){
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Service is still running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    t.show();
}

}
```

And this is how I start the service.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(Log_TAG,"_____________RESTART__________");

    Intent i= new Intent(this, Reminder.class);
    startService(i); 
}
```

Comment: handler.postDelayed(run, POST_DELAY); call first time ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I can think of 2 alternatives to what you are trying to achieve here.

1- Use `TimerTask` in set a repeating task that will call call the required method every 10 seconds.

2- Use `setRepeating` method of `AlarmManager`.

Both these alternatives are way better. You can google search the examples of both to get a better understanding.

Happy Coding :)

**Edit:-** I seem to got your original code working using `Handler`'s `postDelayed()`

```
package com.example.tauben;


import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Reminder extends Service {

Handler mHandler;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @override 
        public void run() {
            f();
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
        }
    };
    mHandler.postDelayed(r, 10000);
}
public void f(){
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Service is still running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    t.show();
}

}
```

Comment: Im currently tryinng it with TimerTask, but I fail

Comment: I just did. Its in the main post.

Comment: the problem lies in the `Timer.schedule()` method. try using `scheduleAtFixedRate`.. `schedule` is to run the task only once.

Comment: `public void scheduleAtFixedRate (TimerTask task, long delay, long period)` 

you are calling this method like this `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000, 10000);`

try setting the delay (2nd parameter) to 0 like this `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 10000);`

This shall definitely do it.

Comment: I changed it (I edited the post again for you), but it still doesnt work :/. I just googled it again but I cant find an answer. The application just stops running, and i dont know how to debug it to find the mistake.

Comment: ok.. I've found the thing that was going wrong.. `TimerTask`s run on a different thread and not on the `main` thread or the `UI thread`. So when you are calling `f()` it contains `Toast` which needs a `UI thread` to run on. So as long as you dont have any UI operations to perform in `f()` you'll be fine with the above code. Else you'll be needing to use `Handler`'s `postDelayed()` method. Will edit my answer and provide you with the snippet consisting the use of `Handler` and `postDelayed()`

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna try it this afternoon. Hopefully it works. Thanks a lot <3

Comment: Okay I just tried it. It causes the same problem like at the beginning: It works, but I cant stop it. I tried to stop it with   Intent i= new Intent(this, Reminder.class);
  stopService(i);

Comment: ae you trying to stop the service from within itself??? Then you might be interested in a method called `stopSelf()`

Comment: Thanks. Now I just need to find out how notifications work. :D

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is bind to service and declare a method where service clients can stop the service. Inside that method you have to call handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) to cancel all runable tasks.

Comment: I'm a beginner. I cant follow you.